# Codeigniter 2.0 undefined function decrypt()

Tags: codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter site that I just migrated from php4 to php5 and 1.7.2 => 2.0.  Now I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function decrypt() in path_to_file/global/utility.php on line 7
```

Line in question:

```
$isAdmin = isset($login[3]) ? (decrypt($login[3])=="1" ? true : false) : false;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A few questions for you:

Why did opt to upgrade to CodeIgniter 2.0 when the more stable release is 2.1?

Did you follow the migration instructions at the following when upgrading?

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html

The code line in question looks like part of an Auth system. Is this something that you created yourself, or an auth system like Ion_Auth or TankAuth that's been circulating around?

Can you fill us in on this information?

Comment: Is this function has been converted to a object method ? like here :- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it may be part of a helper of other library that you didn't port over. Tank_Auth and ion_auth utilize the built-in CI encryption methods so my guess is that someone created a custom decrypt function somewhere that has not been ported over or called in your new version. Perhaps there is a missing entry in your autoload config.

Also, you will likely need to re-encrypt the encrypted data as stated in the user guide encryption manual referenced by ajreal.